# Preventing jQuery event triggering from sub elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I have the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="a">
      <div id="b">
        <script type="text/javascript">
              $('#b').bind('fuffle',function() {alert('b fuffled');})
        </script>
        <div id="c"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run:

```
$("#b").trigger('fuffle')
```

I get the alert box as I would expect. However, when I run:

```
$("#c").trigger('fuffle')
```

I also get the alert box. I am guessing this because c is nested in b, however, is there a technique where this behavior could be avoided.

In my code, sub elements can also trigger fuffle, but they are bound to a different method.
This behavior is literally causing a JS stackoverflow error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing the event to your anonymous handler function like

```
...'fuffle', function(e) {alert...
```

then call

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

which will prevent the event bubbling. The more blunt approach is to return false.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: Also, hopefully your example is spurious but you are assigning the jquery event handler with inline script so this line could be hit before the jquery library has loaded

Comment: Yeah, this was just for the sake of demonstrating my problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript events bubble up the DOM. You can either:

- Check the [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to see if the event originated from #c or one of its children, in the event handler bound to `#c`, or
- Bind an event handler to `#b` that [stops the event from propagating](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

maybe have a simple check

```
$('#b').bind('fuffle',function(){
    if($(this).attr("id") == "b"){
        alert('b fuffled');
    }
});
```